# How can i plot R data in Pycharm?

Tags: r, pycharm

i installed R plugin in Pycharm to run R in Pycharm.
Actually, i can run R code, also i can get result of code in R language.
But the Graph which i plot is not shown at  area..

this is my R code.

```
mycars <- within(mtcars, {
  vs <- factor(vs, labels = c("V", "S"))
  am <- factor(am, labels = c("automatic", "manual"))
  cyl <- ordered(cyl)
  gear <- ordered(gear)
  carb <- ordered(carb)
})

gears <- table(mycars$gear)
barplot(gears, main =  "Title : Car gear distribution",
        xlab = "Number of Gears", col = "#05ae99")
am <- table(mycars$am)
print(am)
```

and i can not get Graph in Plots area..
how can i plot in Pycharm?

Comment: There's a tool window called "R Tools" in Pycharm. You may want to check its "plots" or "viewer" panels.